# .uniq does not work in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a table in my view and I want it to show only unique value from the database. I have tries `@savedHTML.each.uniq` and `@savedHTML.domain.each` and all my values are still shown. I have tried them both in the view and controller and nothing

view

```
<table class="listing" summary="Links list">
    <tr class="header">
      <th>Domain</th>
      <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
    <% @savedHTML.each do |page| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= page.domain %></td>

      <td class="actions">
        <%= link_to("Delete", {:controller => 'page_scraper', :action => 'delete', :id => page.id}, :class => 'action delete') %>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
```

controller

```
def index       
         @savedHTML = ScrapedPage.all

    end
```

Comment: which values do you want to be unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing uniq on your records, but it seems you want the uniq according to the domain attribute (it doesn't make sense to get unique records from your active record relation, since all of them are unique). If you want unique records by domain attribute, you can do something like:

```
def index       
    @savedHTML = ScrapedPage.all.uniq{|p| p.domain}

end
```

However, it doesn't seem to make sense to me either, cause you have a delete button, so like that you'll delete only one record with the uniq domain. It's not really clear what you want, but good luck!